# Two versions of the program depending on the input parameter without code duplication

Tags: c++

I am solving the following problem. I am working on an optimization program in C ++ which, depending on the initial settings of the user, uses various regulations (standards) to calculate the target function. Suppose we have a method A based on some norm and a method B based on another norm to calculate the target function. The user is setting the right standard before starting the program. The rest of the code is the same. During optimization, the target function is iteratively called over and over again. Of course, there is a simple solution: each time the target function is called, the IF condition is used to decide which standard to use. But because the program has to make decisions in every iteration, it seems to be ineffective. The second option is to create 2 independent codes and run only the one with the required standard. This, in turn, is ugly in terms of duplicate code.

I imagined that I would create 2 different classes and use the selected class using the IF condition when constructing the object. This would make the program decide only once when creating the object, but during the iteration itself the object would be clearly defined. Unfortunately, this does not work because objects cannot be created in IF conditions.

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------
// Create object sensor based on input
if(data.sensors_tipe == "Uniaxial_025") Sensor_Uniaxial_025 sensor(data);
else if (data.sensors_tipe == "T_rosette_05") Sensor_T_rosette_05 sensor(data);
else report.error("some error");

// rotation test
int element_index = 1;
double orientation_angle = 3.490658503988659;
sensor.rotate(element_index, orientation_angle);
```

Another way I would like is to set the correct method using a parameter in the constructor. Unfortunately, that probably isn't possible either.

I am a beginner and I did not find the answer anywhere. So maybe someone can help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a good job for templates, which are "recipes" to generate code.

The end result will be duplicated machine code, but without the duplication in the source.

```
template<typename MethodT>
float optimize(const MethodT& method) {
  float v = method();

  // etc...
}


float methodA();
float methodB();

int main() {
  auto a = optimize(methodA);
  auto b = optimize(methodB);
}
```

Comment: Note that to gain the benefit from templates (as opposed to function pointer parameters), the passed functor should be lambdas or classes with `operator()`, otherwise compilers are not likely to inline the call, which defeats the purpose of machine code duplication.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev That is simply incorrect. All modern compilers will trivially optimize regular functions the same way they would a lambda.

Comment: Here, template is useless, you have `optimize<float(*)()>` in both cases.

Comment: @Frank, Yes, I see you are right. In production I still use VS2015, which is not able to optimize this, but modern compilers, including VS2019 do optimize this ( https://godbolt.org/z/sfsP6dGKM )

Answer (score 0):

First, the solution with `if` may be not that bad. It is branch on each function call, but the branch should be predicted well.

Second, if the functions that implement *method A* and *method B* are large enough to miss inlining, use function pointer.

Otherwise, use static polymorphism with templates, *method A* and *method B* may be passed via template parameter as functors.

Answer (score 0):

In case, the user can change standard after programm compilation (for example, before each run) you can create interface and 2 child from it.
So, at startup you should create the instance (one of 2) you need through `new`. And then you can use it.
You can't use that algorithm with stack instances.

Comment: "You can't use that algorithm with stack instances." why not ? Polymorphism does not necessarily require dynamic allocation: https://godbolt.org/z/s7PjT4YvP

Comment: As I undestand the question: requester needs an object (f.e., sensor), he wants to call time-to-time some functions of this object. And (it's my suggestion based on topic example) he should create only one instance of object (creation of some objects with wrong type is useless and bad idea). So, imho, creation object by ```new``` is very good idea, isn't it?

Comment: And (imho) he doesn't want duplicate code of functions calls to each sensor type. So ...

Comment: creating an object with `new` is never a good idea. Use smart pointers for dynamically allocated objects, not raw poitners.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use inheritance.

```
class Sensor
{
public:
    virtual void rotate(int, double) = 0;
};

class Sensor_Uniaxial_025 : public Sensor
{
public:
    virtual void rotate(int, double) {/*stuff*/};
};

class Sensor_T_rosette_05 : public Sensor
{
public:
    virtual void rotate(int, double) {/*stuff*/};
};

Sensor* sensorToUse;

//-----------------------------------------------------------
// Create object sensor based on input
if(data.sensors_tipe == "Uniaxial_025") sensorToUse = new Sensor_Uniaxial_025(data);
else if (data.sensors_tipe == "T_rosette_05") sensorToUse = new  
Sensor_T_rosette_05(data);
else report.error("some error");

// rotation test
int element_index = 1;
double orientation_angle = 3.490658503988659;
sensorToUse->rotate(element_index, orientation_angle);
```

The example above, with new, comes with serious memory management issues. But if you pre-allocate the sensor for each type, in a single instance, and use a look-up instead it works well.

The alternative is with template. See other answers for these approaches.

Comment: You need not dynamically allocate the objects to get virtual function calls. You need a pointer or reference to base, but that does not necessarily imply dynamic allocation. See here https://godbolt.org/z/s7PjT4YvP. And when you do dynamically allocate you still need no `new` but smart pointers. You are missing some `;` btw

Comment: You are totally correct, but if OP insisted in having a single `foo` call outside the if's, then you need either the pointers, or a discussion on why refs can't be reassigned and I tend to no want to add new material to already overwhelmed OPs. :-) Hopefully just pointing out the OOP way helped them.

Comment: OP says that user makes a choice in the beginning and then either one or the other is used. There is no reason to put the object outside of the `if`. In other words, you can always put the `if` around all code in main, only the users chioce has to be made before

Comment: my point is just that you present a solution which is fine in principle, but your code comes with a big issue, using `new` and manually managed raw pointers, when this isnt needed